# How to show custom page on client device connects to router (TP Link MR3020 ) with OpenWRT?

Tags: openwrt, captiveportal

I have installed OpenWRT on my TP Link MR3020 successfully and I was also able to configure the firewall to redirect all domain/IP request on 80 port to a router admin portal.

Now what I am looking for is when Android/iOS device connects to router then it should automatically open a website/ip address request on browser/webview?

Anyone having idea, help would be appreciated?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options to do that:Nodogslash,Wifidog,Coovachilli

You can take a look on these link:

https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/wireless.hotspot.nodogsplash

https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/wireless.hotspot.wifidog

https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/wireless.hotspot.coova-chilli